# Template of template parameter with GCC

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang

I'm trying to use template of template as parameter, everything is ok when I compile with clang but when I try with GCC 4.8 I have the following error:

> can't deduce a template for 'TReceiver' from non-template type 'DamageAnimationSystem'

Here is my situation: I've got a program where classes can subscribe to the event manager for  some type of events but not all.

To do that, I inherit from a class with a specific type:

```
 class DamageAnimationSystem : public Receiver<DamageEvent>, 
                               public Receiver<HealthEvent>
```

Here, my class will listen "DamageEvent" and "HealthEvent" so I need to declare virtual methods for this type of events:

```
DamageAnimationSystem::onEvent( const DamageEvent& event ) {}
DamageAnimationSystem::onEvent( const HealthEvent& event ) {}
```

And I need to subscribe to this event:

```
DamageAnimationSystem::DamageAnimationSystem()
{
    eventManager->subscribe<DamageEvent>(this);
    eventManager->subscribe<HealthEvent>(this);
}
```

As I said before, everything is ok when I use Clang but when I use GCC I've got the error given above.

Here is what I've done:

**Receiver:**

```
class EBaseReceiver
{
protected:
    static std::size_t nextId;
};

template <typename TEventData>
class Receiver : public EBaseReceiver
{
friend class EventManager;
public:
     virtual void onEventReceive( const TEventData& event ) = 0;
     static std::size_t getId() { return ID; }
private:
     static std::size_t ID;
};
```

**Event:**

```
struct BaseEvent
{
protected:
     static std::size_t nextId;
};

template <typename T>
struct Event : public BaseEvent
{
     static std::size_t getId() { return ID; }
     static std::size_t ID;
};

**And finally the event manager:**
template< class TEvent, template<class> class TReceiver>
void EventManager::subscribe( TReceiver<TEvent>* receiver );
{
    const std::size_t eventId = TEvent::getId();
    this->subscribers[eventId].push_back(receiver);
}
```

**I've made the simulation online to test result : https://ideone.com/vZZhqN**

Thanks a lot for your help!

PS: I need compatibility with GCC because I need to use this code with android NDK and thread didn't work with clang on last NDK.

## EDIT

I'm trying to use another method with std::function and std::bind:

**Receiver:**

```
class Receiver {};
```

**Event:**

```
template <typename T>
struct Event : public BaseEvent
{
    friend class EventManager;
    static std::size_t getId() { return ID; }
private:            
    typedef std::function<void( const T& event )> EventCallback;
    static std::size_t ID;
    static std::vector<EventCallback> listeners;
};
```

** EventManager **

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <typename TEvent>
void emit( const TEvent& event )
{
    const auto& listeners = TEvent::listeners;
    for( const auto& listener : listeners )
        listener(event);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template< class TEvent, class TReceiver>
void subscribe( TReceiver* receiver )
{
    TEvent::listeners.push_back(std::bind( &TReceiver::onEventReceive, receiver, std::placeholders::_1));
}
```

I've got the following error on std::bind:

```
No matching function for call to 'bind'
Candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Fp'
Candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Rp'
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Could you add the `EventManager` method which raises events? Thats where the virtual functions are called, and thats where the errors probably are. I think you should use virtual inheritance in your receivers: You are inheriting from multiple distinct receivers, and the vtable of the receiver should dispatch to the correct receiver class, isn't?

Comment: OTOH there are aproximations to this problem much easier to implement. Consider this: Which is really an event? A collection of callbacks, and a receiver is just a callback. But a callback is not a function only, could be ***any callable entity***. So I suggest you to use `std::function` instead of receiver classes. Playing a bit with the concept you could make an event class which allows any kind of callable entities be receivers (Function pointers, lambdas, functors, **member functions**, global functions, etc).

Comment: Do you really have more than one `Reciever` type `class TEMPLATE` you need to support?  Delete `TReciever` and change the parameter to `Reciever<…>`

Comment: The problem can be boiled down to the following http://ideone.com/lSkS80, `clang` is wrong to accept it. **in other words**; *your code is illformed*.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.
@Manu343726: Indeed, I'm finally trying to use std::function and std:: bind to resolve the problem but it look like std::bind didn't like template parameter (I edit my post with the update I've made).
Yakk: I've tried but behind that, the compiler didn't know the Receiver's type and use the wrong ID from 'EBaseReceiver' (I didn't receive right event during simulation).
Refp: So Clang is wrong, I will try to use function and bind like Manu343726 said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following compiles (don't link): https://ideone.com/EheCok

I explicit the template argument that way:

```
eventManager.subscribe<HealthEvent, ::Receiver>(this);
eventManager.subscribe<DamageEvent, ::Receiver>(this);
```